# I can't start SonarQube in CENTOS 7 because the PIDs keeps on changing rapidly

Tags: linux, postgresql, jenkins, sonarqube, centos7

I am trying to Integrating Jenkins 2 and SonarQube 6.7.3 on centos 7 due to this tutorial:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osc0j_Z1x0w

I install and config all software like: java, PostgreSQL, SonarQube,... I am really confused how to start sonar correctly in order to be able open sonar dashboard on Firefox by `http://localhost:9000/` now i can't open it because the sonar service not started correctly and **PID keeps on changing rapidly** :

```
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is running (36211).
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is not running.
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is running (36602).
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is running (36602).
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is not running.
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is running (36993).
[root@localhost ~]# service sonar status
SonarQube is running (36993).
[root@localhost ~]#
```

[sonar can't be opened on FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuGOC.jpg)

I start and enable PostgreSQL by this commands :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start postgresql-9.6
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable postgresql-9.6
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status postgresql-9.6
● postgresql-9.6.service - PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-07 11:44:12 +0430; 1h 26min ago
Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/
***Main PID: 1288 (postmaster)***
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-9.6.service
        ├─1288 /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
        ├─1626 postgres: logger process   
        ├─1630 postgres: checkpointer process   
        ├─1631 postgres: writer process   
        ├─1632 postgres: wal writer process   
        ├─1633 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
        └─1634 postgres: stats collector process   

May 07 11:43:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 
database server...
May 07 11:44:11 localhost.localdomain postmaster[1288]: < 2018-05-07 
11:44:11.217 +0430 > LOG:  redir...ess
May 07 11:44:11 localhost.localdomain postmaster[1288]: < 2018-05-07 
11:44:11.217 +0430 > HINT:  Futu...g".
May 07 11:44:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL 9.6 
database server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

when I run the command again `systemctl status postgresql-9.6` the output is the same as last run with `Main PID: 1288 (postmaster)` :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status postgresql-9.6
● postgresql-9.6.service - PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-07 11:44:12 +0430; 1h 29min ago
Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/
***Main PID: 1288 (postmaster)***
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-9.6.service
       ├─1288 /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/
       ├─1626 postgres: logger process   
       ├─1630 postgres: checkpointer process   
       ├─1631 postgres: writer process   
       ├─1632 postgres: wal writer process   
       ├─1633 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
       └─1634 postgres: stats collector process   

May 07 11:43:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 
database server...
May 07 11:44:11 localhost.localdomain postmaster[1288]: < 2018-05-07 
11:44:11.217 +0430 > LOG:  redir...ess
May 07 11:44:11 localhost.localdomain postmaster[1288]: < 2018-05-07 
11:44:11.217 +0430 > HINT:  Futu...g".
May 07 11:44:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL 9.6 
database server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

but when I start and run sonar, the outputs are different and Main PID keeps on changing rapidly :

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start sonar
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable sonar
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status sonar
● sonar.service - SonarQube service
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-07 13:19:57 +0430; 6s ago
  Process: 121807 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop 
  (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 121850 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start 
  (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  ***Main PID: 121893 (wrapper)***
  CGroup: /system.slice/sonar.service
       ├─121893 /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/../../conf...
       └─121895 java -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m - 
       Xmx32m -Djava.library.pat...

       May 07 13:19:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sonar.service 
       holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
       May 07 13:19:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube 
       service...
       May 07 13:19:56 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[121850]: Starting 
       SonarQube...
       May 07 13:19:56 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[121850]: PID:
       May 07 13:19:56 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[121850]: 
       "/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper" "...be"
       May 07 13:19:57 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[121850]: Started 
       SonarQube.
       May 07 13:19:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SonarQube 
       service.
       Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
       [root@localhost ~]#
```

the previous command `Main PID: 121893 (wrapper)` and the other command is `Main PID: 123382 (wrapper)`

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status sonar
● sonar.service - SonarQube service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-07 13:21:11 +0430; 3s ago
Process: 123296 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 123339 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
***Main PID: 123382 (wrapper)***
CGroup: /system.slice/sonar.service
       ├─123382 /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper 
       /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/../../conf...
       ├─123384 java -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m - 
       Xmx32m -Djava.library.pat...
       └─123411 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161- 
       0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java -XX:+UseCo...

       May 07 13:21:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sonar.service 
       holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
       May 07 13:21:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SonarQube 
       service...
       May 07 13:21:10 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[123339]: Starting 
       SonarQube...
       May 07 13:21:10 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[123339]: PID:
       May 07 13:21:10 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[123339]: 
       "/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper" "...be"
       May 07 13:21:11 localhost.localdomain sonar.sh[123339]: Started 
       SonarQube.
       May 07 13:21:11 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SonarQube 
       service.
       Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: are you trying to run the sonar in the context of 'sonar' user or the default user?

Comment: Do you know what actually launches sonar? Because PID's don't change, what must be happening is one process exits (crashes maybe, or gets an early error and exits) and something relaunches it and this is happening over and over.

Comment: @VighneshPai I'm trying to run sonar in the context of 'sonar' user

Comment: @Quantic how to found out what program launches sonar?

Comment: my problem is solved, sonarqube should be installed and configured with non root user, I do this steps :                                                       1. I stopped the service. 
2. Reassigned all the ownserships ("chown -R sonar:sonar /opt/sonarqube-6.6")
3. Changed #RUN_AS_USER= in /opt/sonarqube-6.6/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh line 48 to RUN_AS_USER=sonar and both the sonarqube service and its elasticsearch service restarted without further problems. I was left having to go to http://<sonarhost:port>/setup to upgrade the database and from there everything worked fine.